# Bedeutung des Wortes "stossend" im Schweizer Hochdeutsch

Tags: meaning, swiss-german

Die Neue Zürcher Zeitung schreibt in einem [Kommentar](https://www.nzz.ch/meinung/die-neue-ubs-wird-zu-einer-staatsbank-und-die-politik-wird-mitreden-wollen-ld.1731357) zur  erzwungenen Übernahme der Credit Suisse durch die UBS

> Dass die neue UBS staatsnaher denn je erscheint, hat auch juristische Gründe. Der Bund musste, ähnlich wie bereits in der Pandemie, auf Notrecht zurückgreifen, um die Übernahme ins Ziel zu bringen. Das ist für ein Land, das sich mit gutem Grund etwas einbildet auf seine rechtsstaatlichen Traditionen, mehr als **stossend**.

Ich gehe davon aus, dass es sich bei "stossend" um das Wort  "stoßend" in Schweizer Schreibweise handelt.

**Was bedeutet das Wort in diesem Kontext?**

Meine Vermutung geht in Richtung

- abstoßend
- anstößig

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/stossend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Anstößig* oder *anstoßerregend* wären passende Synonyme außerhalb des schweizerischen Hochdeutsch.